# How to read events from Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

How do I read custom events from the Google Analytics API (e.g. with the help of `gapi.class.php`)?

If I have three events (myEvent1, myEvent2 and myEvent3) and they all belong to eventCategory myEventCategory, how do I read that data?

I have been searching the API docs but found nothing on retrieving the results of event tracking.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You would set your [dimensions](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/dimsmets/dimsmets.html#q=event&cats=visitor,session,trafficsources,adwords,goalconversions,system,geonetwork,pagetracking,internalsearch,eventtracking,ecommerce,customvars,time) to:

`ga:eventCategory, ga:eventAction, ga:eventLabel`

And then you'd set your [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#filterSyntax) to:

`ga:eventCategory==myEventCategory`

Comment: @Yahel what about the metrics? leave it blank?

Comment: @user2636556 It will not work if you leave it blank. Fill it with `ga:totalEvents` or `ga:uniqueEvents`.

Comment: For me [code]ga:eventCategory==myEventCategory[/code] does not work. It gives me: "Invalid dimension or metric"...

Comment: @Mollo you could try test it here: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/